# Need to use \pmb for bold math fonts

Tags: accents, superscripts, boldmath

I need to submit my LaTeX source files to an IEEE journal. My paper contains bold math font, for which I used `\bm{...}` as recommended by most LaTeX users.

Apparently, the journal does not use `\bm` but `\pmb`, which is not only ugly but also has disastrous effects on the placement of sub-scripts/upper-script, as well as when used in combination with `\hat` and `\tilde`.

An example:

[image: fhat]

Everything is fine with `\bm`, the upper-script A is well placed and the "hat" is aligned. In contrast, with `\pmb` the "hat" is misaligned and the upper-script A is way too high.

Now I *must* use `\pmb` because that is what the journal uses. How can I change my code so that I can use `\pmb` and have a correct placement of "hat" and upper/sub-scripts?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me guess: the journal wants you to use  `mathptmx`. You may be able to convince them that `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` essentially produces the same result and `\bm` works correctly. Welcome to TeX.SX! You have all my sympathy, as I'm not sure you'll be able to convince them. :(

Comment: well you can't really. `\pmb` just overprints the characters three times, slightly offset so the base is just a series of boxes so you can not easily get any of the normal fine adjustment of accent positioning. The Journal will be using their own fonts anyway (if it is a commercial journal) so just submit using whatever they tell you to do the author typeset version is only a manuscript. (If it's a camera ready journal things are a bit different)

Comment: @egreg `mathpx` isn't required apparently. I managed to get in touch with one of the staff editor. He told me that they were using PlainTeX, which does no allow them to use `\bm`. That being said, I guess I could put everything within the `\pmb{...}`. I can live with a bold "hat". However I would like to keep the upper-script A non-bolded.  Is there a way to force it?

Comment: Don't. Use the syntax they want you to use. The semantics is crucial here - the output is not. You need to write what you mean. The journal is going to end up using their fonts anyway and you don't know what they will do with `\pmb{...}` but the result is not going to look as it looks to you. Unless they are taking stuff camera-ready (in which case, they'd not need stuff consistent with plain), they are going to mess around with it anyway. Just check the proofs.